# Error while executing bash script

Tags: bash

I have a file named `1.txt` which contains numbers, like `2, 30,20,1 etc.` I am trying to compare each number in this text file with a numeric value `20` and I would like to run a command if the value is equal to `20`, otherwise exit.

My code is given below. When I try to run the bash script, getting error as

```
----------
email.sh: line 2: [[2: command not found
email.sh: line 2: [[1: command not found
```

---

```
for f in $( cat 1.txt ); do
   if [[$f -eq "20"]];
   then
      echo "sucess"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Try to use spaces in between variable and square brackets like so `[[ $f -eq "20" ]];`

Answer (score 1):

You should have space after the `[[` in the if

```
 if [[ "$f" -eq "20" ]];
```

**Example**

```
$ if [[ "$f" -eq "20" ]];    then       echo "sucess";    fi
sucess
```

**Why?**

In bash the `[[ ]]` construct is called [extended test ***command***](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS), and you always need to separate tokens in any language with spaces.

Comment: `]]` is no command, both of them are keywords. Together you can possibly call it a test command: `[[ ]] is the extended test command`

Comment: @Jahid Sorry, but I think I wrote the same _In bash the [[ ]] are extended test commands,_

Comment: the part `are` and command`s` are wrong. You are attributing them separately as commands, that's syntactically wrong, i.e both of them are not commands, together they imply a single command.

Comment: @Jahid Got it, I have re formatted the sentence. Hope it is fine now.

Answer (score -1):

There is an error in your if, syntax error. try including space:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $( cat 1.txt ); do

if [ $f -eq "20" ];

then

echo "sucess"

fi

done
```

Comment: quote your variables, it's dangerous to use unquoted variables inside `[ ]` in most cases.

Comment: There's another problem, you shouldn't use string comparison with `-eq`, it's for integers. use `if [ "$f" = "20" ];` instead

Comment: @Jahid The other person who answered did the same thing, she corrected him too?

Comment: `[ ]` is not the same as `[[ ]]`, `[[ ]]` is an extended version which takes care of all the quirks for you.